# Expanded Branch do not show its children for first time in Flex Tree?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, treeview, tree

I have added an event handler for itemOpening event for the tree component inside the handler basically ido myTree.selectedItem = event.item ; and then add the new data inside myTree.selectedItem.children.push(newData);
But It do not show simultaneously instead I have to close , open the branch again to see the new data . I think I need to refresh something after adding new data but dont know what ? 
below is the code but without the declaration , script tag etc

```
<services:DocumentService id="$document"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="$newFolderAdded" result="$newFolderAdded_resultHandler(event)"/>


     <mx:Tree  id="myTree" width="100%" height="60%" creationComplete="myTree_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
                 labelField="name" itemOpening="myTree_itemClickHandler(event)" />

    protected function myTree_itemClickHandler(event:TreeEvent):void
                {
                     myTree.selectedItem = event.item;
                    if(event.item.hasOwnProperty('children'))
                   {
                       $newFolderAdded.token =  $document.getDirectDecendents(event.item);

                   }
                }

        protected function $newFolderAdded_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
                {
                    for each(var folder:Object in event.result)
                    {
                    myTree.selectedItem.children.push(Object(folder));

                    }


                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try invalidating the data of the tree by calling:

```
myTree.invalidateList();
```